# Azure worker role throwing System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net, azure, reflection, azure-worker-roles

I redeployed an operational Azure worker role with a few changes that involve referencing a new class library project I have set up and have begun to see the worker role endlessly reboot/recycle.

The Event Viewer Application logs provide very little help as the error I receive is very generic.

Source: .NET Runtime

> Application: WaWorkerHost.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>   Stack:
>      at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule, Int32, IntPtr*, Int32, IntPtr*, Int32, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ObjectHandleOnStack)
>      at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule, Int32, IntPtr*, Int32, IntPtr*, Int32, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ObjectHandleOnStack)
>      at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule, Int32, System.RuntimeTypeHandle[], System.RuntimeTypeHandle[])
>      at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandle(Int32, System.RuntimeTypeHandle[], System.RuntimeTypeHandle[])
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32, System.Type[], System.Type[])
>      at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(System.Reflection.CustomAttributeRecord, System.Reflection.MetadataImport, System.Reflection.Assembly ByRef, System.Reflection.RuntimeModule, System.Reflection.MetadataToken, System.RuntimeType, Boolean, System.Object[], System.Collections.IList, System.RuntimeType ByRef, System.IRuntimeMethodInfo ByRef, Boolean ByRef, Boolean ByRef)
>      at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule, Int32, Int32, System.RuntimeType, Boolean, System.Collections.IList, Boolean)
>      at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.RuntimeType)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Hosts.Worker.Loader.CreateConsoleRole(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Hosts.Worker.Parameters)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Hosts.Worker.Loader.Main(System.String[])

Source: Application Error

> Faulting application name: WaWorkerHost.exe, version: 2.7.1198.768, time stamp: 0x57159090
>   Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18340, time stamp: 0x57366075
>   Exception code: 0xe0434352
>   Fault offset: 0x0000000000008a5c
>   Faulting process id: 0xf20
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d287c5480b416f
>   Faulting application path: E:\base\x64\WaWorkerHost.exe
>   Faulting module path: D:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
>   Report Id: 85f9c3f7-f3b8-11e6-80c1-0004ff9da18e
>   Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

I've searched for this but haven't come across anyone receiving an error message as generic as this.

My own logging doesn't provide much insight either. All I know is that the WorkerRole doesn't hit the OnStart method.

Are there any other logs that could help narrow down the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out... but not in the most graceful of ways.

I went ahead and updated all DLLs from Nuget for the worker role and class library projects. Something in there fixed that problem (I know, bad right?) but then I was faced with another:

> Application: WaWorkerHost.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
>   Stack:
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.Initialize()
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Implementation.Loader.RoleRuntimeBridge.Initialize(String[] args)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Implementation.Loader.RoleRuntimeBridge.Initialize(System.String[])
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Hosts.Worker.Loader.CreateConsoleRole(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Hosts.Worker.Parameters)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Hosts.Worker.Loader.Main(System.String[])

To solve this, I eventually stumbled across [here](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/thewindowsazureproductsite/en_us_develop_net_tutorials_multi_tier_web_site_1_overview/), which led me to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kwill/2013/10/03/troubleshooting-scenario-7-role-recycling/). I downloaded AzureTools on my Worker Role VM and attached a debugger to the recycling WaWorkerHost process. The following is a relevant excerpt from the aforementioned link:

> AzureTools includes an option under the Utils tab to attach a debugger to the startup of a process.  Switch to the Utils tab, click Attach Debugger, select WaIISHost from the process list, then click Attach Debugger.  You will see WaIISHost show up in the Currently Monitoring list.  AzureTools will attach WinDBG (or whatever you specify in Debugger Location) to a monitored process the next time that process starts up.  Note that AzureTools will only attach the next instance of the target process that is started – if the process is currently running then AzureTools will ignore it.

Debugging through this, I found out that I was missing the `type` attribute for my `filter` tag in the Worker Role's app.config file. Once I added that in as shown below, everything fell into place and the worker role deployed successfully.

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Note that to resolve the first error, I could have also used AzureTools and debugged through that way. In most cases, I would consider that the advisable approach. It just so happens that I didn't find out about the utility until I was confronted with the second error and given that my application has not yet been productionized, I could afford to update my DLL references.

Hope this helps someone else.